# new Backbone.Router.extend ... Difference when using it without the brackets

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, constructor, underscore.js, instance

What is the difference between the following:

```
new Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}});
```

And

```
new (Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}}));
```

**Why does the bottom one output "Created" to the console and the top one does NOT? Why are they so different?**

More interestingly:

```
var tmp = new Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}});
new tmp();
```

produces an error.

The following however outputs "Created".

```
var tmp = Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}});
new tmp();
```

So why and how are they different?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a backbone.js user but I can still answer this question, because, it is mainly related to native javascript.

Explanation for your 1st statement:

```
// All this does is to return the constructor to the variable router
var router = new Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}});    

// To initiatize an instance you do this. This should print "created" in the console.
var obj = new router;
```

In the second statement you're combining both lines of the above code into one. The bracket is executed first i.e. the constructor is returned. Then, 'new' creates an instance:

```
// This is just a short-hand way to execute both the above statements at once
var obj = new (Backbone.Router.extend({initialize: function(){console.log("Created")}}));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those two statements are actually not equivalent. Initializing an instance of router actually causes a JS error. TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Comment: @SimonC In the latter part of your question, try changing the "new tmp()" to "new tmp". Can you let me know if you still get the error?

Comment: @SimonC That's kinda weird now. I don't know about the internals of backbone, but purely from a javascript perspective that should work. :) I just did a quick search. Have a look at this page and how the guy initializes the router object - http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/